# Get text words from query

Tags: mongodb, indexing, full-text-search, mongodb-query

I've read the MongoDB [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/) on getting the indexes within a collection, and have also searched SO and Google for my question. I want to get the actual indexed values.

Or maybe my understanding of how MongoDB indexes is incorrect. If I've been indexing a field called `text` that contains paragraphs, am I right in thinking that what gets indexed is each word in the paragraph?

Either case I want to retrieve the values that were indexed, which `db.collection.getIndexes()` doesn't seem to be returning.

Answer (score 2):

Well yes and no, in summary.

Indexes work on the "values" of the fields they are supplied to index, and are much like a "card index" in that there is a point of reference to look at to find the location of something that matches that term.

What "you" seem to be asking about here is ["text indexes"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/). This is a special index format in MongoDB and other databases as well that looks at the "text" content of a field and breaks down every "word" in that content into a value in that "index".

Typically we do:

```js
db.collection.createIndex({ "text": "text" })
```

Where the "field name" here is "text" as you asked, but more importantly the type of index here is "text".

This allows you to then insert data like this:

```js
db.collection.insert({ "text": "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" })
```

And then search like this, using the [**`$text`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) operator:

```js
db.collection.find({ "$text": { "$search": "brown fox" } })
```

Which will return and "rank" in order the terms you gave in your query depending how they matched the given "text" of your field in the index on your collection.

Note that a "text" index and it's query does not interact on a specific field. But the index itself can be made over multiple fields. The query and the constraints on the "index" itself are that there can "only be one" text index present on any given collection otherwise errors will occur.

Answer (score 0):

As per mongodb's docs:

"db.collection.getIndexes() returns an array of documents that hold index information for the collection. Index information includes the keys and options used to create the index. For information on the keys and index options, see db.collection.createIndex()."

You first have to create the index on the collection, using the createIndex() method:

```
db.records.createIndex( { userid: 1 } )
```

Queries on the userid field are supported by the index:

Example:

```
db.records.find( { userid: 2 } )
db.records.find( { userid: { $gt: 10 } } )
```

Indexes help you avoid scanning the whole document. They basically are references or pointers to specific parts of your collection.

The docs explain it better:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-index/